# Codeigniter does not get the other controller except for the index only

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

Hi im currently working on a project that uses codeigniter and im having a problem with the setup in linux (ubuntu 14.04), this project is setup on a Windows machine and is now being transfered on a linux machine.

the problem is when i go to the default page of the site which is **http://localhost/** it goes to my index (this is workign correctly) but when i go to the other functions in my controller it always gives 404 NOT FOUND.

```
(404 NOT FOUND) The requested URL /lin was not found on this server.
```

here is the sample of the code

```
class Lin extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    public function validate_credentials() {
        var_dump("TEST");
        exit;

        }
```

if i go to http://localhost/lin/validate_credentials it my display the TEST dump and exit but it give the 404 ERROR.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already try

http://localhost/index.php/lin/validate_credentials

Sorry I'm not so sure about which is first I'll correct it.

But if it still doesn't work. There might be something wrong with your .htaccess

Make a file called '.htaccess' in your root directory, yes with a dot in the beginning and inside is this code. When I use this, i generate clean url's without the index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /PUT YOUR ROOT FOLDER NAME HERE , DON'T REMOVE THE SLASH
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$l [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 / index.php
</IfModule>
```

I'm sorry if I can't eplxain this line by line, but I always put this in codeigniter and works perfectly, the just change the RewriteBase, you can search on the internet or in here stackoverflow what it meants.

Comment: The 2nd one worked but i was wondering why do i need the index.php ? and how to eliminate it thanks

Comment: Okay great I'll edit my answer and if it will somehow help you kindly give me an upvote or check mark thanks. @JohnGeliberte

Comment: And also, to add, the index.php is always called by codeigniter by default that's why you need to use it. I'm sorry too I just saw the answer of @Manyank Pandey and I forgot that you use linux now, I do hope i would still be able to help you since I'm more of windows user.

Comment: my root folder is the html folder(lamp) but the controllers are separated from the html folder.

here is my directory order
- codeigniter(code goes here)
- html
 - setup for the codeigniter goes here.

so i put the rewritbase as /html is this correct?

Comment: I think that would be able to work. If not try the other directories until it may work. Also I searched that not all linux are enabled to use htaccess, and from what I see you have admin privileges, you may also enable it using some guides on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of mod_rewrite is not enable on your machine. Try this:

```
1. Enable mod_rewrite by:
sudo a2enmod rewrite

2. Restart Apache:
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It's still the same. it sasys 404 not found.